# How to use 200 mil DIP components on solderless breadboard?

Tags: relay, breadboard, prototyping

I recently got my hands on some miniature DIP relays, and would like to prototype a circuit with them on a solderless breadboard. Unfortunately, these relays have standard 100 mil pin spacing, but 200 mil between rows, rather than the more usual 300 mil. Obviously I can't just put them in at a right angle... is any adapter available to deal with this? Or any cute tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best bet is usually some DIY if you have not got too many.

Use 200 mil centre sockets if available or socket strips,

[image]

or cut a socket in two and solder two strips onto a piece of veroboard/vector board/whatever you call board with copper strips with holes in it.

[image]

Solder socket to board and solder a row of pins through board outside socket so they have (probably) 400 centres which will allow plugging into a standard breadboard.

Something like below  but with your two rows of socket pins in the centre and with pins to breadboard bottom soldered

[image]

You can buy pins suited to this - and I have used plated brass dressmakers pins in days of yore. The plated brass pins have about 3 million% better solderability than non-brass pins that I have tried, even though the brass is under the plating.

Answer (score 4):

Solder wires to the relay pins and stick the other ends of the wires into the breadboard.  After all, **it's a breadboard**, meaning it's for one-off testing.  Geesh, sometimes people get so hung up in the process they forget the original intent.

Comment: Aye. That works, but it do rather muck up the relays for socketed use thereafter :-).

Comment: If these relays fit into sockets, then you can solder wires to a spare socket instead of the relay.  In any case, this is only a 1 or 2 minute problem.